# iptables: Index insertion too big

Tags: centos, iptables, vnc

I am trying to configure VNC on my server. I found this guide which seems very easy: https://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/how-to-install-vnc-server-on-centos-6/

Lastly, I got to iptables configuration:

when I run this command as exactly as guide told:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 5 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp -m multiport --dports 5901:5903,6001:6003 -j ACCEPT
```

I terminal throws this message:

> iptables: Index insertion too big

What does it mean? And How can I fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That means that you're trying to insert the rule at a position that doesn't exist in the table.

In this case `-I INPUT 5` tells `iptables` to insert the rule on position `5` of the `INPUT` table but the table is shorter than that.

That guide apparently assumes some pre-existing rules that you don't have.  I looked at it and it doesn't show what they expect.

It would ***most likely*** be OK to simply skip the `5`:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp -m multiport --dports 5901:5903,6001:6003 -j ACCEPT
```